# Laravel Envoy setup task not completing successfully

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, gitlab, laravel-envoy

I'm trying to set up deployment with GitLab and Docker but can't get through the initial setup in the official Laravel Docs about Envoy setup.
I can't connect through my host with Envoy for some weird reason.

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/). Any help is appreciated. Could it be an issue with my host? I run the command on my local machine.

```
envoy run list
```

I get this error:

> [✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.

My SSH login works, so I am out of ideas.

**Envoy.blade.php**

```
@servers(['web' => 'MY HOST HERE'])
@task('list', ['on' => 'web'])
    ls -l
@endtask
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it locally first? Perhaps the server you entered is incorrect.

```
@servers(['web' => 'localhost'])
@task('list', ['on' => 'web'])
    ls -l
@endtask
```